# How do you use split and scan to parse a URI in ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, split, uri

Let's say I have this string in Ruby

`str = "/server/ab/file.html`

I want to get an array that contains

`["/server/", "/ab/", "file.html"]`

Is there a way to obtain this array using split or scan? I have tried all kinds of combinations with nothing matching exactly what I want. I can't use any outside libraries. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: No. It is impossible to let the single slash to be doubled in the end of `"/server/"` and the beginning of `"/ab/"` with a single pass of `split` or `scan`.

Comment: Is there a way to check for the slash at the beginning and if it doesn't have it, add it onto the string?

Comment: That will give you `"/file.html"`, not `"file.html"`. By the way, what is the logic for having a preceding slash for `"/ab/"` but not for `"file.html"`?

Comment: @sawa it is possible with single `scan` pass and `map` on the iterator returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sawa stated, the issue is with the double '/' that requires you to manipulate the string.

The most direct solution I can think of is:

```
# removes the '/' at the beginning of the string
# and splits the string to an array
a = str.sub(/^\//, '').split('/') # => ["server", "ab", "file.html"]

# iterates through the array objects EXCEPT the last one,
# (notice three dots '...' instead of two '..'),
# and adds the missing '/'
a[0...-1].each {|s| s << '/'; s.insert(0 , '/')} # => ["/server/", "/ab/"]

a # => ["/server/", "/ab/", "file.html"]
```

**EDIT 2**

Following up with @mudasobwa's concepts, ideas and inputs, if you know that the first character is always a `'/'`, this would be fastest solution so far (see edited benchmark):

```
        a = str[1..-1].split('/')
        a << (a.pop.tap { a.map! {|s| "/#{s}/" } } )
```

Good Luck.

**Benchmarks**

After reading @mudasobwa's answer I was super impressed. I wanted to know how much faster his solution was...

... and I was surprised to see that although his solution is much more elegant looking, it's substantially slower.

I have no idea why, but it seems that the Regexp lookup using gsub or scan is slower in this case.

Here's the benchmark, for anyone interested (iterations per second - higher numbers are better):

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

str = "/server/ab/file.html"
Benchmark.ips do |b|

    b.report("split") do
        a = str.sub(/^\//, '').split('/')
        a[0...-1].each {|s| s << '/'; s.insert(0 , '/')}
    end
    b.report("updated split") do
        a = str[1..-1].split('/')
        a[0...-1].each {|s| s << '/'; s.insert(0 , '/')}
    end
    b.report("scan") do
        str.scan(/(?<=\/)([\w.]+)(\/)?/).map { |(val,slash)| slash ? "/#{val}/" : val }
    end
    b.report("gsub") do
        str.gsub(/(?<=\/)([\w.]+)(\/)?/).map { |m| "#{$2 && '/'}#{m}" }
    end
    b.report("mudasobwa's varient") do
        a = str[1..-1].split('/')
        [*a[0..-2].map { |e| "/#{e}/"}, a[-1]]
    end
    b.report("mudasobwa's tap concept") do
        a = str[1..-1].split('/')
        a << (a.pop.tap { a.map! {|s| "/#{s}/" } })
    end

end; nil

# results:
#
# Calculating -------------------------------------
#                split    39.378k i/100ms
#        updated split    45.530k i/100ms
#                 scan    23.910k i/100ms
#                 gsub    18.006k i/100ms
#  mudasobwa's varient    47.389k i/100ms
# mudasobwa's tap concept
#                         51.895k i/100ms
# -------------------------------------------------
#                split    517.487k (± 2.9%) i/s -      2.599M
#        updated split    653.271k (± 6.4%) i/s -      3.278M
#                 scan    268.048k (± 6.9%) i/s -      1.339M
#                 gsub    202.457k (± 3.2%) i/s -      1.026M
#  mudasobwa's varient    656.734k (± 4.8%) i/s -      3.317M
# mudasobwa's tap concept
#                         761.914k (± 3.2%) i/s -      3.840M
```

Answer (score 2):

```
▶ str.gsub(/(?<=\/)([\w.]+)(\/)?/).map { |m| "#{$2 && '/'}#{m}" } 
#⇒ [ "/server/", "/ab/", "file.html" ]
```

or, with `scan`, that is more semantic:

```
▶ str.scan(/(?<=\/)([\w.]+)(\/)?/).map { |(val,slash)| slash ? "/#{val}/" : val }
```

Probably the fastest solution:

```
▶ a = str[1..-1].split('/')
▶ [*a[0..-2].map { |e| "/#{e}/"}, a[-1]]
#⇒ ["/server/", "/ab/", "file.html"]
```

Complete inplace array change (hey, aesthetes):

```
▶ a = str[1..-1].split('/')
▶ a.pop.tap do |e| 
▷   a.map! do |e| 
▷     [-1, 0].each do |i| 
▷       e.insert(i, '/')
▷     end
▷     e
▷   end.push e
▷ end
▶ puts a
#⇒ ["/server/", "/ab/", "file.html"]
```

Comment: I loved your solution, looks super elegant... I loved it so much I tested it's performance against my own. I have no idea why it's slower, but it's definitely more beautiful :-)

Comment: @Myst because of global scan. You might make yours even faster by changing first `sub` to: `a = str[1..-1].split('/')`.

Comment: @Myst would you mind to add my third variant (just posted) to your benchmarks?

Comment: @mudasobwa Good catch! I didn't do it in fear that the string might not really start with the '/' sign, but you're totally right! I checked the benchmarks and using `str[...]` would be way faster - even with an `if` statement it's twice as fast! Thanks :-)

Comment: @Myst: I added the solution that requires zero additional memory: both an array and strings are modified inplace :)

Comment: @mudasobwa - your edited solution didn't work on my machine, but I took your `tap` concept and put it to the test. Very impressive - see my updated answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa it seems that inlace String editing is redundant for the performance. I assume this is either due to the string's length or since the inserts might require new memory allocations.

Comment: @Myst right, sorry, I’ve forgotten to return `e` to `map!`, fixed. Anyway, your `tap` is way better.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str[1..-1].split('/')
=> ["server", "ab", "file.html"]
str[0...-1].map!{|e| "/#{e}/"} << str[-1]
=> ["/server/", "/ab/", "file.html"]
```

Comment: Nice solution. But, to continue our previous conversation, you are recreating an array and most of the strings, thereby creating new objects when you can simply edit existing ones ;-)     ....    Since this isn't really a long iteration, it might not matter. But, if the code was going into a server application parsing requests, you might want to avoid this. consider using `map!` or editing the strings using `each`. Sometimes creating more objects is fine. In my solution I created a new temporary array to avoid an if statement in my iteration. It's case dependent and it's just food for thought.